# Postgresql Update Based on count, min and group by

Tags: postgresql, select, command-line, group-by, min

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.
I've seen similar questions, but not the same depth. Please help!

I would like to update a column all rows in a table that holds user_id and date_created with the lowest date_created for the user_id.

The following select gives me all the rows I would like to update:

```
select user_id, min(date_created) from mytable s1 where 
    (select count(1) from mytable s2 where 
        s1.user_id = s2.user_id group by s2.user_id) 
 > 1 group by user_id order by user_id;
```

I would have expected this update to work:

```
update mytable set join_status = 1 where date_created = 
    (select min(date_created) from mytable s1 where 
        (select count(1) from simplepay_payment s2 where 
            s1.user_id = s2.user_id group by s2.user_id)
  > 1 group by user_id);
```

But is gave the following error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I've tried a few different solutions, but nothing seems to help.

Does anyone have any ideas fro me?

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want to set the date_created as well, or only the join_status?

Comment: And please supply some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your SQL to:

```sql
update mytable set join_status = 1 where date_created IN
    (select min(date_created) from mytable s1 where 
        (select count(1) from simplepay_payment s2 where 
            s1.user_id = s2.user_id group by s2.user_id)
  > 1 group by user_id);
```

Read more on row comparison in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html).

---

**EDIT:**

In the subquery you're performing `GROUP BY user_id`. This means that you *will* receive many rows, based on the number of unique user_id values in your `simplepay_payment` table.

To make your query working as expected, you should join using 2 columns: `user_id` and `date_created`. As you've mentioned, you already have the query that gives you the correct results, so you can use it like this:

```sql
WITH desired AS (
  SELECT user_id, min(date_created) AS mindt
    FROM mytable s1 where 
      (SELECT count(1) FROM mytable s2
        WHERE s1.user_id = s2.user_id GROUP BY s2.user_id) > 1
   GROUP BY user_id)
UPDATE mytable m SET join_status = 1 FROM desired d
 WHERE d.user_id = m.user_id AND d.mindt = m.date_created;
```

I've wrapped in your query into the [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) and used it in the `UPDATE` statement. You can add `RETURNING m.*` at the end of the query to see the rows that had been updated and their new values.

You can test this query on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/15d6f/2).

---

**EDIT2:**

Common Table Expressions (WITH-queries) are not available before version 9.1 for `UPDATE` statements. You can simply move the CTE subquery into the update, like this:

```
UPDATE mytable m SET join_status = 1 FROM (
  SELECT user_id, min(date_created) AS mindt
    FROM mytable s1 where 
      (SELECT count(1) FROM mytable s2
        WHERE s1.user_id = s2.user_id GROUP BY s2.user_id) > 1
   GROUP BY user_id) d
 WHERE d.user_id = m.user_id AND d.mindt = m.date_created;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I really want to match the min date_created row for each user_id, because it is possible that the date_created is not unique. So I do want to get one row for the subquery. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for the solution and for the link to the fiddle! Problem: the query that I built using your advice works in the fiddle which is version 9.1.3, but not on my server which is 8.4.11. Any ideas? The error I am receiving is syntax error at or near update. Here is the updated query, with quite a bit of data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/dfe4f/2

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. I appreciate you following through to the end, and sending the helpful links. One thing: the 8.4 docs also have with queries in them: see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html .

Comment: Correct, 8.4 has `WITH` queries, but not for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements.